# Determine number of participants in a competition given that each solved 19 out of 20 problems given sum of both answered questions 10 question parts

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

In a test paper, there are 10 problems in Parts A and B each. Each participant who sat for the test
paper has correctly solved exactly 19 out of the 20 problems. For each pair of Part A and Part B
problem, the number of participants that have correctly solved both problems is written down. The
sum of all 100 written numbers is 244, 440. Determine the number of participants in the competition.

How to solve this question please?

I am struggling to figure out "what to count" based on the sums given. I can't seem to see how it relates to the total number of participants. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $100$ possible pairs of questions. Since each participant has missed exactly one question, each participants name is counted under only $90$ of these $100$ pairs, since there are $10$ pairs which include the missed question.

Since each participant's name is counted $90$ times, and the total number of names counted is $244440$, the number of participants is $\frac{244440}{90}=2716$

Comment: Thank you again! I actually understand that